# Prolog DCG select distinct items

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to write a prolog DCG to pick 2 distinct colours in a list, see code below.

```
colour --> [red].
colour --> [blue].
colour --> [green].
...

pick2colours -->
    colour,
    colour.

% I would like to return 2 distinct colours
```

The actual version of the code does not garanty the two colours to be distinct. I don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you want to use grammar rules instead clauses?

Logtalk and some Prolog systems provide a `select/3` library predicate that can solve this problem easily. For example:

```
| ?- select(Color1, [red,green,blue], Remaining),
     select(Color2, Remaining, _).

Color1 = red,
Remaining = [green, blue],
Color2 = green ;
Color1 = red,
Remaining = [green, blue],
Color2 = blue ;
Color1 = green,
Remaining = [red, blue],
Color2 = red ;
Color1 = green,
Remaining = [red, blue],
Color2 = blue ;
Color1 = blue,
Remaining = [red, green],
Color2 = red ;
Color1 = blue,
Remaining = [red, green],
Color2 = green ;
no
```

But note that you will get (by backtracking) repeated solutions if you consider `Color1 + Color2` the same as `Color2 + Color1`...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is loosing information... I would capture the data required to encode the logic:

```erlang
?- [user].
|: colour(C) --> [C],{memberchk(C,[red,blue,green])}.
|: pick2colours(A,B) -->
|:     colour(A),
|:     colour(B),
|:     {A\==B}.
|: ^D% user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 2 clauses
true.

?- phrase(pick2colours(X,Y),[red,green]).
X = red,
Y = green.

?- phrase(pick2colours(X,Y),[red,red]).
false.
```